# What happens when I enter .wq! in vim?

Tags: unix, vim

What happens when I enter `.wq!` in vim?
Is there a way to prohibit that behavior?

Answer (score 1):

use vim's help to understand each of those

`.` - repeat last change - `:h .`

`w` - move cursor to next word - `:h w`

`q!` - `q` would start recording a macro but since `!` isn't a valid register to record the macro to they simply cancel each other

you could add `nmap .wq! <Nop>` to your vimrc to make this combination a noop but I wouldn't recommend doing that. It would make your `.` respond slower since it's a prefix for an existing map so if you ever learn more and start using this feature this mapping will annoy you.

Answer (score 0):

But if you use `:.wq!` it will try to save the current line, overwriting the current file.

Comment: Is there a way to prohibit it?
nmap is not working.....